# Perform groupby.sum for some columns, and groupby.mean for others

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

With my code I have some results in csv and are right, the problem is I need `mean()` the two columns that I'm drop because I don't know why I can sum some columns and mean the others.

I added the csv text to be more specific and my output. Also, the output that I'm looking for!

code:

```
"""Calculate"""
# encoding=utf8

import pandas as pd

dfh = pd.read_csv("este_mes.csv", sep=',')
h = dfh['Fecha'].max()
dfh['Cliente'] = dfh['Cliente'] + "," + h
dfh = dfh.groupby(['Cliente']).sum()

frames = [dfh]

results2 = pd.concat(frames)
results2 = results2.drop('Fill_rate', 1)
results2 = results2.drop('ECPM_medio', 1)
results2.to_csv("Cliente_x_mes.csv", sep=',', index=True)
results2 = pd.read_csv("Cliente_x_mes.csv", sep=',')
```

csv:

```
Cliente,Fecha,Status,cl_fecha,Subastas,Impresiones_exchange,Fill_rate,Importe_a_pagar_a_medio,ECPM_medio
jjj,01/01/2018,Alerta Revenue: aumento Subastadas - descenso eCPM y Fillrate,jjj_01/01/2018,1930916,53231,2.76,17.32,0.33
jjj,02/01/2018,Alerta Fillrate -- Incremento Revenue - Imp Vendidas - Subastadas,jjj_02/01/2018,5930774,98181,1.66,33.2,0.34
jjj,03/01/2018,Estable,jjj_03/01/2018,5487499,97782,1.78,33.37,0.34
jjj,04/01/2018,Estable,jjj_04/01/2018,5254018,98039,1.87,32.95,0.34
jjj,05/01/2018,Estable,jjj_05/01/2018,4904150,98068,2.0,31.58,0.32
jjj,06/01/2018,Alerta Revenue - Imp Vendidas - Subastadas -- Incremento Fillrate: descenso eCPM,jjj_06/01/2018,4904150,98068,2.0,31.58,0.32
kkk,01/01/2018,Alerta Fillrate - Revenue - Imp Vendidas,kkk_01/01/2018,30668,4464,14.56,3.87,0.87
kkk,02/01/2018,Incremento Imp Vendidas - Subastadas: descenso eCPM,kkk_02/01/2018,41032,5707,13.91,4.06,0.71
kkk,03/01/2018,Estable,kkk_03/01/2018,39847,5331,13.38,3.72,0.7
kkk,04/01/2018,Estable: descenso Imp Vendidas,kkk_04/01/2018,37403,4733,12.65,3.37,0.71
kkk,05/01/2018,Estable: descenso Fillrate,kkk_05/01/2018,40330,4473,11.09,3.35,0.75
kkk,06/01/2018,Estable: descenso Subastadas y aumento Fillrate,kkk_06/01/2018,32797,4050,12.35,3.22,0.8
```

The output:

```
Cliente,Subastas,Impresiones_exchange,Importe_a_pagar_a_medio
"jjj,10/01/2018",44367734,946163,303.14
"kkk,10/01/2018",382800,47851,36.47
```

The output I need:

```
Cliente,Subastas,Impresiones_exchange,Importe_a_pagar_a_medio,Fill_rate,ECPM_medio
"jjj,10/01/2018",44367734,946163,303.14,30,0.331666667
"kkk,10/01/2018",382800,47851,36.47,3.598333333,0.756666667
```

On the other hand if you can have the output with only 2 decimals it will be great

Comment: Not sure if I understand you right, but how about removing both the `results2.drop(...)` calls?

Comment: because I have the sum of these columns and and need `mean()` @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**
Split your grouping code into two stages. First, create a `groupby` object, and *then* calculate sum/mean for the appropriate columns.

```
m = ['Fill_rate', 'ECPM_medio']        # columns to calculate mean for
s = df.columns.difference(m).tolist()  # columns to calculate sum for
```

An alternate manner of finding `s` (for numeric columns only) -

```
s = df.columns[df.dtypes != object].difference(m).tolist()
```

Next,

```
# Stage 1
g = df.groupby('Cliente')   

# Stage 2
i = g[s].sum()
j = g[m].mean()

# concatenate results, and save to CSV
pd.concat([i, j], 1).to_csv('Cliente_x_mes.csv')
```

*Details*

`i`

```
         Importe_a_pagar_a_medio  Impresiones_exchange  Subastas
Cliente                                                         
jjj                       180.00                543369  28411507
kkk                        21.59                 28758    222077
```

`j`

```
         Fill_rate  ECPM_medio
Cliente                       
jjj       2.011667    0.331667
kkk      12.990000    0.756667
```

---

**Option 2**
Another way of doing this would be to build an `dict` of functions, and pass it to `groupby.agg` -

```
f = dict.fromkeys(m, 'mean')
f.update(dict.fromkeys(, 'sum'))

df.groupby('Cliente').agg(f).to_csv('Cliente_x_mes.csv')
```

---

`Cilente_x_mes.csv`

```
Cliente,Importe_a_pagar_a_medio,Impresiones_exchange,Subastas,Fill_rate,ECPM_medio
jjj,180.0,543369,28411507,2.0116666666666667,0.3316666666666667
kkk,21.59,28758,222077,12.99,0.7566666666666667
```

Comment: great my friend! Thanks

Comment: @MartinBouhier You're welcome. From future, please use the [python] tag, not [python-2.7].

Comment: @MartinBouhier You are free to use any version as you please. I use python3 almost always, but the switch takes some getting used to, as there some important underlying differences. On the whole, there are more features in python3. Note that if your question does not pertain to a version specific feature, there's no need to use a version specific tag.